# PHP URL /?val=something

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I was messing around on [WolframAlpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com) today and noticed that you start out on the wolframalpha.com/index.html page then when you hit `enter` you get redirected to wolframalpha.com/input/?i=YourSearch

I know how to set this up, `<form action="newpage.php" method="GET" />` but with the project I'm working on, it would be cool if I could redirect to `example.com/?val=something` instead of `example.com/newpage.php?val=something` Is it possible to redirect to a file but have the page name hidden like WA has? Would this be a job for .htacess?

**EDIT:**
I need to direct from index.php to pages/file.php without "file.php" showing up in the url of the browser. So if I were to say:

```
<form action="pages/file.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
</form>
```

Then if would direct me to example.com/?foo=blah instead of example.com/pages/file.php?foo=blah

Comment: It usually works right the opposite: within `.htaccess` you specify the URL rewrite rule so `example.com/` becomes processed as `example.com/some_new_php.php`.

Comment: If no file name is specified, the according `index.php` of the referenced directory will receive the request; on Apache setups for example.

Answer (score 0):

If `index.php` is the script loaded if you access `www.example.com/`, having a form on this page with `<form action="">` will do this.